# How to finish running playwright tests in pipeline?

Tags: testing, azure-pipelines, pipeline, playwright, npx

After running the Playwright tests in command line (e.g. by command `npx playwright test`), it always shows

```
  Serving HTML report at http://localhost:0000. Press Ctrl+C to quit.
```

How to avoid pressing Ctrl+C to quit and quit stream automatically? So I can use playwright in a pipeline (Azure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could figure it out.

In pipeline I added a variable `CI=true`.

Locally I fixed it by adding file `.env` and added `CI=true` there. In the config I added this `reuseExistingServer: true` to `playwright.config.ts`:

```
  webServer: {
    command: 'ng s',
    url: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    reuseExistingServer: true
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `open: 'never'` in the config file:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    reporter: [
        ['html', { open: 'never' }],
    ],
}
```

...or just remove the entire reporter if you don't need the html report at all